# SQL specific Query Correction

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Can anyone tell, what is wrong in this query, I am a student using Oracle APEX. I got this error :  ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

```
SELECT t.BandDesc, TypeDesc, CustomerID, PaymentAmount, TotalPayment FROM

(SELECT Room_Dim.BandDesc, Room_Dim.TypeDesc, CustomerID, PaymentAmount
FROM Room_Dim, Fact_Bookings_Payments
WHERE Room_Dim.RoomID = Fact_Bookings_Payments.RoomID)t 

LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT ConcertID, CustomerID, TotalPayment
FROM Fact_Buy)t2

ON t.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID;
```

I need to find : For each room band and concert, produce the cumulative income of 4-star TypeDesc rooms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t` and `t2` both have a `CustomerId` and you use that in the join condition; however, on the first line you select `CustomerId` without specifying which table it comes from. This is where the error is probably coming from.

```sql
SELECT t.BandDesc,
       TypeDesc,
       t.CustomerID,        -- Either this
       t2.CustomerID,       -- Or this
       PaymentAmount,
       TotalPayment
FROM   (
  SELECT Room_Dim.BandDesc,
         Room_Dim.TypeDesc,
         CustomerID,
         PaymentAmount
  FROM   Room_Dim
         INNER JOIN Fact_Bookings_Payments
         ON Room_Dim.RoomID = Fact_Bookings_Payments.RoomID
) t 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ConcertID, CustomerID, TotalPayment
  FROM Fact_Buy
) t2
ON t.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID;
```